# Qt Creator clang code model "could not parse an included file" warning and errors in derived template classes

Tags: qt, qt-creator, c++17

I use the clang code model in Qt Creator. It always worked fine, including a case where I override a method in a class derived from a template base class and when using C++17 features. Then I switched to Qt Creator 4.5 and suddenly I got the error "only virtual member functions can be marked 'override'" even though the code hadn't changed.

Now I tried going back to Qt Creator 4.4 and deleting all settings, but it's still the same.

On top of that, when I open a new file I get the warning "The code model could not parse an included file, which might lead to slow or incorrect code completion and highlighting, for example. type_traits:3083:7: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction" and I get the error "error: no type named 'optional' in namespace 'std'.

This only affects the code model, ie. the warnings and errors Qt Creator shows me within the IDE. Compiling still works fine.

Here is my configuration for the code model:

> -Weverything -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-c++98-compat-pedantic -Wno-unused-macros -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wno-global-constructors -Wno-gnu-zero-variadic-macro-arguments -Wno-documentation -Wno-shadow -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-c++11-extensions -std=c++1z

I tried it with and without setting `std`, but that didn't change anything.

Here is a minimal example that causes "error: use of undeclared identifier 'std'", "error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type constrcution" and "error: use of undeclared identifier 'x'":

```
#pragma once

#include <optional>

class Test {
public:
    void bar() {
        std::optional<int> x;
    }
};
```

Any clues what might have changed or which settings I might be missing?

Comment: which compiler are you using?

Comment: We use GCC 7.2.

I just compiled Qt Creator myself, linking against clang 5.0.1. That resolved the pseudo-error issues. However, I still get the warning "The code model could not parse an included file, which might lead to slow or incorrect code completion and highlighting, for example. type_traits:3083:7: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction"

Comment: I am using osx and xcode, even with latest LLVM and gcc shipped with xcode update, I dont have <optional> header yet. So can not help much.
In fact there are many features of C++17 which are yet to be shipped with all compilers. Just for your reference how far behind these LLVM and MSVC++ most advance compilers are
http://clang.llvm.org/docs/index.html and 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/12/19/c17-progress-in-vs-2017-15-5-and-15-6/?utm_source=vs_developer_news&utm_medium=referral

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been an issue with Qt Creator. It has been resolved in version 4.6, which uses a newer version of clang.